# What is this rectangular icon (Android 11)

Tags: android-11, motorola

Android 11, Motorola G8 Power. Maybe I'm going senile, but I don't recall seeing this rectangular icon to the left of the wi-fi icon. I added a yellow arrow.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Same icon: [Strange status bar icon on Samsung devices after using Developer Options](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212350/44325)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange status bar icon on Samsung devices after using Developer Options](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212350/strange-status-bar-icon-on-samsung-devices-after-using-developer-options)

Comment: Enabled autorotate (had not knowingly disabled it); icon now gone. Thanks everybody.